# Class simulating a connection among two pins

Tags: c#, observer-pattern

Following [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106378/class-simulating-a-circuit-pin-follow-up) and [the one before that](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106030/class-simulating-a-circuit-pin), here I am asking for a review on another piece of code: the connection among two pins. As usual, be merciless in your review. Here it goes:

```
public class PinConnection : IObserver<Pin>
{
    #region variables
    private Pin _from;
    private Pin _to;
    private IDisposable _fromUnsubscriber;
    private IDisposable _toUnsubscriber;
    #endregion

    #region properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set the label of this PinConnection object.
    /// </summary>
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public Pin From
    {
        get
        {
            return _from;
        }
        set
        {
            _from = value;

            if (_fromUnsubscriber != null)
            {
                _fromUnsubscriber.Dispose();
            }

            if (_from != null)
            {
                _fromUnsubscriber = _from.Subscribe(this);
                _from.Notify(_from);
            }
        }
    }

    public Pin To
    {
        get
        {
            return _to;
        }
        set
        {
            _to = value;

            if (_toUnsubscriber != null)
            {
                _toUnsubscriber.Dispose();
            }

            if (_to != null)
            {
                _toUnsubscriber = _to.Subscribe(this);
                _to.Notify(_to);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region constructors
    public PinConnection()
    {
        Code = string.Empty;
        Label = string.Empty;
    }

    public PinConnection(Pin from)
        : this()
    {
        From = from;
    }

    public PinConnection(Pin from, Pin to)
        : this(from)
    {
        To = to;
    }
    #endregion

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        throw error;
    }

    public void OnNext(Pin value)
    {
        if (value.Equals(From) && To != null)
        {
            To.Value = value.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how I feel about this.

> ```
> public void OnCompleted()
> {
>     throw new NotImplementedException();
> }
> ```

In my opinion, if you're going to implement a contract, you should fulfill the contract, even if that means doing nothing at all. There's little more frustrating than getting an object that you believe implements an interface only to find out that it doesn't *really* implement it. Oh no, *this* implementation throws an exception when I call that method. Now, my nice clean code that, previously, didn't care what concrete type it was passed has to type check it's args to make sure it's not an instance of this class you've created.

Ok. So I do know how I feel about it. I hate it. I really really hate it. I'd much rather that you fulfill the contract by truly not implementing it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Does nothing. Not implemented for reasons.
/// </summary>
public void OnCompleted() { }
```

Now my code doesn't have to type check for your class anymore. Even better, I know *why* you've not implemented this part of the contract and decided that this method should just do nothing at all when called.

Of course, if it's not going to do anything, then we can hide it from the public interface of the concrete type by [explicitly implementing the interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx).

```
/// <summary>
/// Does nothing. Not implemented for reasons.
/// </summary>
public void IObserver.OnCompleted() { }
```

Comment: Good points on the contract, and hiding the unimplemented methods.

Comment: Good points. I was actually thinking about the first point but wasn't sure if it was considered a good practice

Comment: @GentianKasa don't take my answer as anything canonical. It's just my personal opinion on the matter. I honestly wasn't sure about it when I started writing my answer, but the more I thought about it, the more I thought "I wouldn't want to consume this class the way it is". Side note: mind sharing the link to your project?

Comment: @RubberDuck didn't take it for anything canonical, it was just better than what I was doing, and the fact that I already thought about it and other people agree (while no disagreement came forth) is proof enough :)
As for the project, you can find it [here](https://bitbucket.org/gkasa/circuitmanager), but it's still in its early stage, so it's pretty blank

Comment: Thanks @GentianKasa I'll check it out. I've been toying around with some embedded dev, so you peeked my interest.

Comment: Feel free to download and play around with the code. One of these days I'm also going to add some additional info on the roadmap etc.